# Do not insert duplicate values into mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert users in mysql without duplicate values at the field "User" .how to show a message to the user when he writes a "User" already exist in the table before he complete the rest of the fields and before he clicks on the button Login?

```
 public void Registrar() throws SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement st = null;

        String user;
        String pass;
        String pass2;
        String email;
        String country;

        user = jTextField1.getText();
        pass = jPasswordField1.getText();
        pass2 = jPasswordField2.getText();
        email = jTextField2.getText();
        country = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();


  if (user.isEmpty()) {
            jLabel8.setText("Please enter an Username");
        } else if (pass.isEmpty()) {

            jLabel8.setText("Please enter an password");

        } else if (pass2.isEmpty()) {
            jLabel8.setText("please you must confirm your password");

        } else if (!pass2.equals(pass)) {
            jLabel8.setText("passwords do not match");

        } else if (email.isEmpty()) {
            jLabel8.setText("Please enter an valid email");

        } else if (country.equals("Choose your country")) {
            jLabel8.setText("Please choose a Country");

        } else {

               String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(User,Pass,Email,Country) "
                    + "VALUES('" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + email + "','" + country + "')";

            try{


                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/whichmovie", "Asis", "dekrayat24");
                System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos SQLite");

                PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.execute();
                pstm.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Congratulations you have created your account");
                dispose();
                Login l = new Login(null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
                l.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "An error has occurred ,please try later");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You should make the column unique and catch the error on insert, ortherwise you will need to verify before, but in that case, there could be another insert meanwhile.